# MYSQL float value can't update if the first number behind comma is 0

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I want to ask about MySql float format. I tried to insert float value for example `12345.66` and it inserted without error and the value is exactly the same. but if i tried to insert value like `12345.01`, value inserted is like this `12345.00`. I have tried any value that have `.0*` and it always inserted as `.00`. Why is that happend?

I tried both using MYSQL from terminal and from phpmyadmin.
sorry for my bad english.

here is my MYSQL version:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.23                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1           |
| version                 | 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Here is my create table. all that float have the same problem.

```
CREATE TABLE `angsurantempo` ( 
`ID` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`NoPA` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`Periode` int(11) NOT NULL,
`TglEfektif` datetime NOT NULL,
`Pokok` float(18,2) NOT NULL,
`Bunga` float(18,2) NOT NULL, 
`Denda` float(18,2) NOT NULL,
`Hari` int(11) NOT NULL,
`TglPost` datetime NOT NULL,
`LogPost` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`IDKop` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`IDKop`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

My Insert Query:

```
INSERT INTO angsurantempo VALUES ('11372','PA-201708-002','15','2017-08-26 00:00:00','1882755.08','2261277.05','0','31','2017-08-30 15:16:00','PAA-201708-007','MAS1')
```

This MYSQL server is installed in VPS Ubuntu

Comment: Could you please share the structure of your table

Comment: I mean on your terminal, type this command `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name \G`

Comment: i have edited my question. adding the show create table. thanks for answering my question

Comment: I can't replicate your problem on MySQL 5.6. What does your `INSERT` query look like?

Comment: I have included one of my upload query in my post. I can't replicate that problem in my PC and laptop too. My laptop is running the same MYSQL version but with ubuntu 18 and my PC running mysql version 5.0. Both my laptop and pc didn't have that problem if i insert value on float with 0 be the first number after dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `decimal(7,2)` data type to store exact decimal value.

Comment: Yes that's working fine. But i want to know why is float cannot store exact decimal value? it only happen in my VPS. in my local PC, float can store that exact decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

### IF you want to insert 12345.01, it is impossible

I don't think you can place comma(,) after the decimal point

Comment: no, i mean if the first number behind dot is `0` then all value behind dot is set to `00` even if i insert value like `.01` or `02` etc, all of that become `00`

Comment: can I see the structure of you table. Use SHOW CREATE TABLE [ table name] query

Comment: There u can see in my question. i have updated it. thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

You should change the data type of that field in the table from float to double with this command

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name
MODIFY your_column_name DOUBLE NOT NULL;
```

Comment: yeah i'm trying. But why is only float from my mysql can't use that format? This server is running in VPS. that is my problem. I have mysql with the same version on my pc and it can store value using that format.

Comment: Which mysql version is your VPS running and another thing, are you inserting the values manually or using a programming language with interface somewhere

Comment: @laurentiuskevin the fundamental problem here is that  `FLOAT(18,2)` is a valid but nonsensical column definition.  The `FLOAT` data type only has 4 bytes to work with, so numbers with more than 6 significant digits cannot necessarily be stored without rounding.  The anomaly here is the local one -- the VPS is behaving more like what would be expected. You should never use `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE` unless you have a specific reason to do so -- which is to say, "almost never" -- if you are unsure whether you have such a reason, then you do not have such a reason.  Use `DECIMAL`.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot, that makes sense, thank you for that